# Longest Increasing Path in a Matrix Applying greedy by calc maxmium path sum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

```
Input: nums = 
[
  [9,9,4],
  [6,6,8],
  [2,1,1]
] 
Output: 4 
Explanation: The longest increasing path is [1, 2, 6, 9].
```

Usually Greedy wont work for Longest Increasing path.

So I thought to create a new 2d matrix of same length in which maximum path sum will be store that will look like this for above matrix :

```
   [9 ,18,22],
   [15,24,32],
   [17,25,33]
```

Now Im thinking of applying greedy over this matrix ie. whosever would be greater between top,left,right,bottom i will move at coordinate  and increment no of step by 1 until reach 2,2 from 0,0.

but after creating the maximum path sum matrix , Im bit confused as how can I approach in dfs as explained above . Im new to the dp and graph problems.

Comment: What does the sum have to do with an increasing sequence? Please clarify the exact task you are trying to solve.

Comment: Do DFS from every matrix element to calculate longest increasing path. You'll notice that the subproblems are being solved repeatedly. Due to such overlap it qualifies for being a Dynamic Programming problem. Save the state that "at <this> coordinate, <this> is the longest increasing path achievable". You've already tagged the problem with DP.

Comment: Based on my above comment, try it out yourself first. Let us know if you face any difficulty and show us what you have tried.